# Option select to dynamically change next selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using a lightbox called featherlight. I have a form inside of that lightbox that requires a dynamic select option to change the content of the next question select box.

The select box works outside of the lightbox yet inside it fails.

Any ideas where I appear to be going wrong?

```
<select>
  <option value="111">111</option>
  <option value="222">222</option>
</select>


<select>
  <option value="111">111</option>
  <option value="222">222</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){ // when one changes
            $('select').val( $(this).val() ) // they all change
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: What's it do inside the lightbox?

Comment: Uh, setting the value of a select to the same value as it currently has, does not usually trigger anything, it just looks strange. jQuery has a `trigger` method that will trigger jQuery event handlers, did you try that ?

Comment: @adeneo do you have example, I am a little unsure as to what you mean?

Comment: Maybe light box replaces your selects with clones or something.

Comment: @tymeJV it fails to change the secondary list options within the lightbox so the second list remains the same. Outside of the lightbox it works fine.

Comment: It's probably an event delegation issue, try: `$(document).on("change", "select", function() { $('select').val( this.value ) });`

Comment: @user3520443 -- I posted a quick answer and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is most likely being added after the handlers are bound - you can use `.on` to get around this:

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function() { 
    $('select').val( this.value ) 
});
```

You should replace `document` with a container that is present at the time of page load and contains your dynamic content - else this event is going to fire each time the `document` is changed (and check if a `select` was actually changed)

With a common class:

```
<select class="common">
    <option value="111">111</option>
    <option value="222">222</option>
</select>


<select class="common">
    <option value="111">111</option>
    <option value="222">222</option>
</select>

$(document).on("change", "select.common", function() { 
    $("select.common").not(this).val( this.value ) //added .not(this) since we dont need to change the value of the select being interacted with
});
```

Comment: There is one problem now, when you select this, it affects all of the other select boxes within the form... so it changes them too

Comment: Well yes - you're selector is simply `select` - it targets all `select` elements on the page. Use a common class if you wish to target a select few.

Comment: I tried to but it frazzled it all, could you modify for me? I know thats so cheeky but this is driving me insane :(

Comment: @user3520443 -- Updated the answer with a sample

Comment: So, with the new changes, the first box has now listed all of of the second boxes items.

http://jsfiddle.net/uEEyT/

Comment: Ignore that I was being a dummy. The problem I am actually having it that if I select one of the options it stays n the same one...

Comment: So how can I separate the two lists out? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

have unique id for both select as follow

```
<select id='select1'>
  <option value="111">111</option>
  <option value="222">222</option>
</select>


<select id='select2'>
  <option value="111">111</option>
  <option value="222">222</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#select1').change(function(){ // when one changes
            $('#select2').val( $(this).val() ) // they all change
        })
    })
    </script>
```

**Updated**

I guess you are accessing parent element from child window

try the following

```
window.parent.$(#select2.val( $(this).val());
```

Comment: Still the same I am afraid, the options just do not change when they within the lightbox, they work outside of it?

Comment: ID's shouldn't matter in this case